# How to open File Explorer using HTML/Javascript/Polymer/Chrome API

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm programming in HTML/JavaScript/Polymer/Chrome API and I need to be able to open a file explorer. Is there any concepts you would suggest in order to go about this?

Comment: `<input type="file">`

Comment: I could not find that on google no matter how I worded it. Thanks a bunch I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to open explorer to select folders?

Comment: Web sites have very little access to the local filesystem, for security reasons. I'm afraid the only option available (without browser plugins like Flash or Java) is that file input tag.

Comment: ahhh I see. I decided to move over to using the Chrome API to do more secure access of system files. Works like a charm and I didn't have to write much code